# Solve differential equation $y\cdot (y')^2+(x-y)\cdot y'-x=0$

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, analysis

I'm working on differential equations and I saw this exercise on my book. I have been trying with no success...

The exercise is the following:

Solve
$$y\cdot (y')^2+(x-y)\cdot y'-x=0$$

and say which is the open interval I in which each solution is defined.

It is not linear, nor exact, not homogeneous either...

Thanks for the assistance and best regards.

Comment: Welcome to MSE! Please use the [basic tutorial and quick reference guide](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference) and review the [Meta Read](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/9959/how-to-ask-a-good-question/9960#9960) and enhance your question to provide your motivation/attempts.

Answer (score 1):

You can factor this equation as
$$
(y'-1)(yy'-x)=0.
$$
Any solution can be subdivided into segments where one of these factors is zero,
$$
y(x)=x+A\text{ or }y(x)=\pm\sqrt{x^2+B}.
$$
A switch between factors is possible where both factors are zero at the same time, that is, on the line $y=x$. This does not give new solutions.